# Convert sed command from linux to freebsd / macos

Tags: sed

I have a very small script that someone here helped me with. It deletes all tracks that are under 1000bits. Works great under linux. Works as well under freebsd and macos but spits out a lot of error messages, saying too many arguments on the sed part, which is getting annoying. Can someone please help me converting this to work nicely under freebsd / macos? Thank you

```
for flacfile in *.flac; do
    [ $(mediainfo "$flacfile" | grep 'Bit rate' | grep -oi '[0-9].[0-9]*'
| sed 's/\s//g') -lt 1000 ] && rm "$flacfile"                                                                          $
done
```

Error message

```
/usr/local/bin/flac-remove: command substitution: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
/usr/local/bin/flac-remove: command substitution: line 6: `| sed 's/\s//g''
```

Comment: `sed 's/[[:space:]]//g'`

Comment: Make sure that this is in **one line** without newlines: `[ $(mediainfo "$flacfile" | grep 'Bit rate' | grep -oi '[0-9].[0-9]*' | sed 's/\s//g') -lt 1000 ] && rm "$flacfile"`

Comment: Thank you both so much. Adjusting the sed command like Wiktor said and putting everything on one line, tanks to Cyrus, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### suggestion 1

Use `[[` `]]` for numeric testing in `bash`

```
for flacfile in *.flac; do
    [[ $(mediainfo "$flacfile" | grep 'Bit rate' | grep -oi '[0-9].[0-9]*'
| sed 's/\s//g') -lt 1000 ]] && rm "$flacfile"                                                                          $
done
```

#### suggestion 2

Replace `grep 'Bit rate' | grep -oi '[0-9].[0-9]*' | sed 's/\s//g'` with single `awk` command

```
awk '/Bit rate/ && /[0-9].[0-9]*/{gsub("[[:space:]]","");print}'
```

So that:

```
for flacfile in *.flac; do
    [[ $(mediainfo "$flacfile" | awk '/Bit rate/ && /[0-9].[0-9]*/{gsub("[[:space:]]","");print}') -lt 1000 ]] && rm "$flacfile"                                                                          $
done
```